# Managing nuget updates in local nuget repository

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, manage-nuget-packages

Let's suppose there is a .NET Core project that has a reference to a nuget package say nugetD. That nuget package in turn have references to 3 other nuget packages say nugetA, nugetB and nugetC. 
The nuget packages are managed locally in a local nuget repository.

When the nuget package nugetD is modified and new version is pushed into the nuget repository then Visual Studio will alert us in the "Manage Nuget Packages" window saying there are updates for that nugetD.

Is there a way to alert us using any tool if let's suppose any of the underlying dependent packages (for nugetD): nugetA, nugetB and nugetC were modified and new versions were pushed to the local nuget repository?

How can the parent nuget package know or track that if they have any dependent child nuget references were modified and that the parent nuget package needs to update to the latest dependent packages?

Comment: One way would be for the project to also have PackageReferences to the child NuGet packages. Then Visual Studio would show updates for the child dependencies since the project is directly referencing them. An another way would be for the parent NuGet package to update its child dependency versions. Then they would automatically be updated when the parent package is updated.

Comment: For the first approach, I was not looking at adding references of child nuget packages in the project twice. As for the second approach, parents packages and child packages are created by different people and they reside in different VS solution. So, if child packages are updated and published, until and unless someone open the solution for parent package they won't know that their child packages are outdated. I'm looking at this https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/index.html which might work in my case.

Comment: Paket is probably a good option. Not sure what you mean by adding the child nuget packages to the project twice - they would only be added once to the project. If you only have the parent NuGet package added to the project then NuGet restores the lowest version of the child dependencies that is compatible.